# Clear Project Path from PYTHONPATH on Mac OS X

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pydev

I am using macOS 10.14.1. I am new to Python and eclipse (PyDev). I first created project with name "PyDevelopment" and while creating project in Eclipse I chose to add it in PYTHONPATH but forgot to create SRC folder. Then I deleted physical project directory from finder ( I guess this is big mistake I did). Now I want to create same project again but Eclipse gives error that Project already exists. I guess it is due to entry made to PYTHONPATH previously. Please let me know how do I remove previous entry and create project with same name (which I deleted physically by deleting directory of that). More when I print $PYTHONPATH it gives me blank value. I am using python3.6. Let me know if more detail is required.

Comment: It is done now. I opened Python Package explorer and delete project using Eclipse and then again deleted physical directory. I am able to create project again with same name.

Comment: Still I am interested about how to edit PYTHONPATH variable. I am using Eclipse with PyDev plugin.